# Is it possible to draw an UIView and its subviews to a graphic context?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, pdf-generation, quartz-graphics

I have an UIView that represents a simple list and an image. I'm looking for a way to export this list, exactly how it looks in the UIView into a PFD file, avoiding the need to arrange and draw the elements again. Something like:

```
CGPDFContextBeginPage(myPDFContext, &pageDictionary);
    //draw here the UIView into the context
CGPDFContextEndPage(myPDFContext);
```

I tried to use `renderInContext` method but only the view is drawn, without its subviews.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like there should be a better way, but you could just iterate over all subviews and call `renderInContext` on them too.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid that, as the elements are also nested. And even the calling itself would not be a problem (I'll do it recursive) the order in which the elements are added one above the other will probably be a problem.

Comment: renderInContext doesn't appear to do subviews